# How to pass ENV argument to Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, rake

I'm trying to invoke another rake task from within another rake task. However, the task I'm trying to invoke accepts `ENV` parameters, not `args`. The file I'm trying to invoke is here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-rails/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb

I'd rather not re-write the `import.rb` so I'm trying to invoke it with

`Rake::Task["elasticsearch:import:model"].invoke("CLASS='User' SCOPE='active' FORCE=y")`

However, the parameters aren't passed in because `import.rb` uses ENV parameters. Is there a way I can pass ENV parameters? Here's the excerpt in `import.rb` that uses ENV parameters.

```
  total_errors = klass.__elasticsearch__.import force:      ENV.fetch('FORCE', false),
                              batch_size: ENV.fetch('BATCH', 1000).to_i,
                              index:      ENV.fetch('INDEX', nil),
                              type:       ENV.fetch('TYPE',  nil),
                              scope:      ENV.fetch('SCOPE', nil) do |response|
```

Comment: any chance to try the answer out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do either set ENV before you invoke, e.g.

```
namespace :importer do 
    task :userimport do 
        ENV['CLASS']='User' 
        ENV['SCOPE']='active' 
        ENV['FORCE']=y
        Rake::Task["elasticsearch:import:model"].invoke
    end
end
```

Or, just use system() method, like so:

```
namespace :importer do 
    task :userimport do 
      system("rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='User' SCOPE='active' FORCE=y")
    end
end
```

I prefer the former one, though.